# ShellExecuteEx code 31 error any time I try to launch an EXE, how to find problematic driver?

Tags: windows-10, shell, windows-error-reporting

I don't know if this is the right forum for this question, so please direct me elsewhere if needed.

I am having a new issue launching .exe files. I keep receiving the following error:

```
ShellExecuteEx failed; code 31.
A device attached to the system is not functioning.
```

Specifically, I have recently tried to launch the following EXE and get that error:
uninstall_flash_player.exe 
R-3.6.3-win.exe 
Rtools35.exe

These are all downloaded from legit sources (Flash remover from Adobe website; R packages from R-CRAN).

I've restarted my computer a million times and I don't have any external hard drives plugged in. When I right-click and Run as Administrator, it still says gives the error box, "A device attached to the system is not functioning."

Based on [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc725584(v=ws.10)), it looks like it is a driver issue, but I am not sure how to find out what driver is the culprit.

Windows 10, ASUS TUF, laptop is about 2 yrs old, issue just started a couple weeks ago (noticed it when I tried to uninstall Flash and just ignored it... now it's an issue I can't ignore)

**Update**
I restarted in safe mode, dropped the User Account Control (UAC) settings down to the lowest level, and this resolves the issues. I can run the EXE files and I can run Command Prompt as Administrator in non-safe mode.

I am not sure why this fixes things, as my account already is sent to Administrator. In the past, there would just be a pop-up window that said, "hey, you're about to make admin changes, is that ok?" So, I don't know what has changed.

I then changed the UAC settings back to the default. Following @BenN's question in the comments, I ran `reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` in a non-elevated command prompt window, and this is the result, but I don't know what it means.

[image]

Comment: There isn't necessarily any device or driver involved - some developer may have [picked an error code unwisely](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20181203-00/?p=100375). Does the Registry key `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` exist under either `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, and if so, does it have an `EnableShellExecuteHooks` entry?

Comment: @BenN the same error is thrown even when I try to run command line as admin. I think it's something related to UAC that I haven't been able to figure out yet. I am not sure how to check for the registry keys, but I will research and try that, thank you

Comment: To open the Registry Editor for browsing the Registry, you can press Windows+R and run `regedit`. If you can't open that due to this error, you can list the contents of a Registry key in a *non*-elevated command prompt with e.g. `reg query HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` (or `HKLM` instead of `HKCU`). In case of malware, it might be worth doing a [Microsoft Defender offline scan](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help-protect-my-pc-with-microsoft-defender-offline-9306d528-64bf-4668-5b80-ff533f183d6c).

Comment: @BenN I can do Defender quick and full scans, but the offline scan doesn't start. I click get to Step four here (https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/42305-how-run-microsoft-defender-offline-scan-windows-10-a.html), click scan, and nothing happens--step 5 doesn't pop up. I think there is something wrong with my UAC. I tried to do the scan in safe mode, but there are no scan options in safe mode, which I was surprised to see.

Comment: @BenN I ended up going into safe mode and dropping the UAC down to the lowest level. That seems to resolve all the EXE related issues and I can run command prompt as admin. I was also able to run the offline defender scan; it ran without issue. I also ran `reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` in a normal command prompt, and the output is shown in in the edited question above. I am not sure what it means. Thanks for your help troubleshooting

Comment: OK, that output means ShellExecute hooks (which might be from malware) are not enabled, which is good. I'm not sure what the problem was then, but I'm glad you found a workaround!